# Load dynamic Content in Tabs present in popup

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

[image]

I have a button, which when clicked opens up tabs. These tabs contains divs container1, container 2 etc. I want to load charts on these divs. I have already tried these charts as individual pages, where they work fine since i use $(document).on('pageshow', '#index', function(){ }); But now when i try to use this in tabs, how to call corresponding div's function???

my code is here

```
<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header">
  <h1>Slide 5</h1>
  </div>

  <div id="divmain" data-role="main" class="ui-content" style="height:40%">

   <a href="#popupBasic" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow                 ui-btn-inline" data-transition="pop">Basic Popup</a>
<div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">
 <div data-role="tabs" id="tabs">
  <div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a id="firstTab" href="#one" value="verify">one</a></li>
      <li><a href="#two" data-ajax="false">two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#three" data-ajax="false">three</a></li>
      <li><a href="#four" data-ajax="false">four</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="one" class="ui-body-d ui-content">
        <div id="container1" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

    <h1 id="tab1">First tab contents</h1>
  </div>

  <div id="two">
    <div id="container2" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

    <h1 id="tab1">Second tab contents</h1>
  </div>

  <div id="three" class="ui-body-d ui-content">
       <div id="container3" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    <h1>Third tab contents</h1>
  </div>

  <div id="four" class="ui-body-d ui-content">
    <div id="container4" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    <h1>Fourth tab contents</h1>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

  </div>
</div>


</body>
```

Code for one particular chart is here

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#index', function () {
    // Set up the chart
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'column',
            margin: 75,
            options3d: {
                enabled: true,
                alpha: 15,
                beta: 15,
                depth: 50,
                viewDistance: 25
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Chart demo'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Data for Sales'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                depth: 25
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]
    });


    // Activate the sliders
    $('#R0').on('change', function(){
        chart.options.chart.options3d.alpha = this.value;
        showValues();
        chart.redraw(false);
    });
    $('#R1').on('change', function(){
        chart.options.chart.options3d.beta = this.value;
        showValues();
        chart.redraw(false);
    });

    function showValues() {
        $('#R0-value').html(chart.options.chart.options3d.alpha);
        $('#R1-value').html(chart.options.chart.options3d.beta);
    }
    showValues();
});
```

So how to call particular function for every tab???

Comment: Can you make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: do you want to render all 4 when page shows? or render each one only when that specific tab is shown? In your Highcharts method, you would just pass in the individual div ids instead of 'container' for the renderTo option.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the Highcharts creation code in a function and pass in the container id (also other params for the data, title, etc.)

```
function MakeChart(containerid){
     // Set up the chart
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: containerid,
            type: 'column',
            margin: 75,
            options3d: {
                enabled: true,
                alpha: 15,
                beta: 15,
                depth: 50,
                viewDistance: 25
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Chart demo'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Data for Sales'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                depth: 25
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]
    });   
}
```

Then either on page show or when each tab shows, call the function with the appropriate container id:

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#index', function () {
   MakeChart("container1");
   MakeChart("container2");
   MakeChart("container3");
   MakeChart("container4");
});
```

In this example I am rendering all 4 charts on pageshow.

> Here is a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/gjCUw/)**